# An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a problem with open graph.
When I use debug facebook tools I have this error message :

```
"error": {
  "message": "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 2
}
```

When I use Graph API Explorer with token generator :

Type POST : https://graph.facebook.com/1145358260/univercial:read
Add a New field : lesson   http://www.filmslive.net/cours-6

It's ok!!!

This is my code :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="fr-FR" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> 
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# univercial: http://ogp.me/ns/apps/univercial#">
    <title>Univercial | Read <?php echo $nom; ?>Lesson</title>
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="429852050395283" /> 
    <meta property="og:type" content="univercial:Lesson" /> 
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.filmslive.net/cours-6">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Read <?php echo $nom; ?> Lesson" /> 
    <meta property="og:description" content="1ére Plateform d'interraction entre les jeunes étudiants du Maroc" /> 
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.filmslive.net/images/200_200.jpg" /> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : '429852050395283', // App ID
                status     : true, // check login status
                cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml      : true
            });
        };

        (function(d){
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js";
            d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
        }(document));

        function postRead() {
            FB.api('/me/univercial:Read?Lesson=http://www.filmslive.net/cours-6', 'post', function(response) {
               if (!response || response.error) {
                    alert('erreur');
                } else {
                    alert('ok');
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
                            <form>
                                <input class="float_left bouton_vert" type="button" value="Read" onclick="postRead()" />
                            </form>
```

Result : alert('erreur')

I can use feed, but, I can't use publish_actions.

Comment: Your code doesn't show that you logged in with the app. Did you do an FB.login somewhere and ask for publish_actions permissions?

Comment: Did you fix this? I'm having the same error, even when doing the request by hand using the browser

Comment: I'm getting the exact error on iOS SDK today.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this.